# add3 instruction for a+b+c with one single rounding

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, instruction-set, instructions

#### Background

It is well known that the exact product of two floating point numbers is *not* always a floating point number, but the error `exact(a*b) - float(a*b)` is. Some codes for exact multiplication exploit this by returning the two numbers

```
res = a * b
err = fma(a, b, -res)
```

This makes use of the [fused-multiply-add instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set) which returns the expression `(a*b)+c` *with one single rounding*.

#### Question

Now, I would like to do the same for *sums*, i.e.

```
res = a + b
err = add3(a, b, -res)
```

`add3` is supposed to return the expression `(a+b)+c` *with one single rounding*.

I wasn't able to find hints that `add3` actually exists in the real world except [in this article](https://doi.org/10.1137/030601818).

Is there a CPU instruction set that contains `add3`? Are there languages implementing it?

Comment: Are you talking about SIMD or scalar operations here ? You have an `sse` tag and a Wikipedia link to SIMD FMA extensions in AMD/Intel CPUs, but your example above is for the scalar `fma()` function in C/C++ ?

Comment: The question is about "`add3`", not `fma`.

Comment: Fine - but is the context scalar or SIMD, and are you looking for a specific architecture (e.g. x86) or is it a more general question ? And why the `sse` tag ?

Comment: I was just wondering if such an instruction exists anywhere at all or if it's just a numerical analyst's dream right now. The flag `sse` was inappropriate, I removed it.

Comment: OK - thanks for the clarification - I'm not aware of any such instruction, but it's somewhat clearer now what you're looking for.

Comment: Ping @EricPostpischil...

Comment: Not available as an instruction on any major processor architecture (yet), but this publication shows how it can be emulated quite easily: Sylvie Boldo and Guillaume Melquiond, "Emulation of FMA and Correctly Rounded Sums: Proved Algorithms Using Rounding to Odd", *IEEE Transactions on Computers*, Vol. 57, No. 4, April 2008, pp. 462-470

Comment: @PaulR: Eh, nearly six-year ping response.

Comment: Do you need a fully general `add3` for any three representable numbers, or do you just want to compute the `err` and `res` shown?

Answer (score 2):

The `err` and `res` requested in the question are provided by the Fast2Sum algorithm in *Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic* by Jean-Michel Muller *et al*, Birkhäuser, 2009, page 126, section 4.3.1, “The Fast2Sum Algorithm.” The book credits it to Dekker in 1971 with earlier appearance of its operations by Kahan in 1965:

Given a floating-point format with a base less than or equal to 3, with subnormal numbers, and numbers `a` and `b` representable in that format with |`a`| ≥ |`b`|, then, using round-to-nearest:

```
s = a+b;
z = s-a;
t = b-z;
```

computes `s` and `t` such that `s` is the floating-point number nearest to `a`+`b` and `s`+`t` = `a`+`b` exactly. (Hence `s` and `t` are the `res` and `err` requested in the question.)

|`a`| ≥ |`b`| is more than sufficient; the algorithm only requires the floating-point exponent of `a` be at least the exponent of `b`, but merely comparing the values may be easier. So a complete implementation needs something like `if (fabs(b) > fabs(a)) swap(&a, &b);` before the above code.

There is a proof in the book. (There is an erratum for the proof; it assumes, without loss of generality, that `a` > 0. That may be corrected in the second edition.)

This does not provide the suggested general `add3` function, just the specific case. `add3` is provided by the `CorrectRoundedSum3` function by Boldo and Melquiond on page 201, section 6.3.4. It manipulates the encoding of floating-point numbers, which raises performance and portability issues. That manipulation is limited to an increment or decrement, so the standard C `nexttoward` function might serve in its place, although that is not necessarily any better for performance.

Comment: This is Algorithm 1.1 in the article I linked. The idea of an `add3` instruction would be to merge the last two steps into a single operation `add3(a, b, -s)`.